# Copying Cookie From Another Domain To My Domain

Tags: php, regex, cookies, curl, setcookie

I'm making a cURL request from `exampleA.com` to get its response header. So far so good, these are some of the data I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  sess=1; path=/; expires=Wed, 15-May-2013 09:25:29 GMT; domain=.exampleA.com; HttpOnly
    [1] =>  .........
)
```

Now this is the hard part for me, I want to set the cookie to my own domain `exampleB.com`, the same as how I got it from `exampleA.com`.

Using Firebug this is the Response Header in `exampleA.com`:

```
Set-Cookie:uuid2=4511997856767122744; path=/; expires=Mon, 12-Aug-2013 09:21:38 GMT; domain=.exampleA.com; HttpOnly
```

So I need to set the cookie to the same values, but under the domain of `exampleB.com`. How do I do that?

Comment: You cannot read cookies from another domain.

Comment: im using CURL to get the response header from domainX.

Comment: @crypticツ, you're correct, im using CURL. #ChamingaD why the downvote?

Comment: @WonderingCoder I didn't downvote o.O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.google.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

preg_match('/Set-Cookie:[^\r\n]+/', $response, $match); // extract cookie header
$cookie_header = preg_replace('/domain=[^;\r\n]+/', 'domain=.mydomain.com', $match[0]); // replace old domain with your domain

//echo $cookie_header;
header($cookie_header); // set cookie header
```

Comment: sorry, what I want to know is how to set cookies I got from the curl to my own domain. Please read my post, im having a hard time setting the cookies just like from domainY.

Comment: @WonderingCoder see edit, just replace `.mydomain.com` with your domain.

Comment: your solution work men! I love you <3. hahah. Thank you very much for the help.